# How to add child element to head tag using DOMDocument

Tags: php, dom

I am trying to arrange document by collecting distributed `<style>` tag into one and delete all of them  then add the new one into `head`, and i have written this snippet, but missing to how to add the new `style` tag into header

```
    ob_start('ob_postprocess');
// ob_postprocess is our custom post processing function
function ob_postprocess($buffer){
    $d = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
    $d->loadHTML($buffer);

    $x = new DOMXPath($d);
    $t = $x->evaluate("//text()");
    $cc = array();
    foreach($d->getElementsByTagName('style') as $style){
            $cc[]= $style->nodeValue;
            $style->parentNode->removeChild($style);
    }
    foreach($d->getElementsByTagName('head') as $head){
        //add new style tag
    }
    $buffer = $d->saveHTML($d);
    return $buffer;
}
```

Comment: You can't do what you're trying to do with PHP; you'd need to use JavaScript. Though instead of trying to write hacky code to move `<style>` tags to the `<head>`, you'd be better off working out **why** you have `<style>` tags being outputted to the `<body>`, and correcting that behaviour. Style tags should only **ever** go in the `<head>`; having them anywhere else is invalid markup.

Comment: I am using WordPress and some plugins adds these tags randomly

Comment: I know i can make it with javascript,  but the point is i need to know how to do it with the DomDocument

Comment: @ObsidianAge: "Style tags should only ever go in the <head>; having them anywhere else is invalid markup". That's only half true. The W3C HTML 5.2 recommendation allows the style element to be in the body element where-ever flow content is expected. Only the WHATWG's HTML living spec continues to require the style element to be in the head.

Comment: I completely understand but unfortunately some plugins adds it into the body tag and i am trying to correct this.